# Toggling Ads in Microsoft Pubcenter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a number of PubCenter ads on each Windows Phone Page. By default they are all disabled.

I use a Random Generator and a switch to select one to turn on. This works fine with AdDuplex, but when I use Pubcenter I only get an empty space where the ad should be. Does anyone know what I have to do to get these ads to start working?

Comment: If you are using the Windows Phone Emulator the ads will not show, you need to deploy the application on your windows phone for PubCenter ads to show.

Answer (score 1):

Various reasons may cause the PubCenter control to be hidden.

The simplest thing you can do to determine why is to subscribe to the `AdControlError` event in the code-behind of the page, like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    myAdControl.AdControlError += AdControlError;
}

private void AdControlError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    string error = e.ErrorDescription;
    MessageBox.Show(error);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that helped a bunch. Had forgotten to add the correct Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have register with pubcenter, and are setting the AdControl.ApplicationId and AdControl.AdUnitId properties?  if you have done that then it should all be good to go.

And these are the settings while you are designing/developing the app:

```
adControl1.ApplicationId = "test_client";
adControl1.AdUnitId = "Image480_80";
```

Comment: Yes, I have subscribed to pubcenter and configured my ads correctly. They work properly unless their inital IsEnabled = false and Visibility = Collapsed